# How to structure a sentence describing a range with over two values?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

When we are given a range within 2 values, we could write the sentence as 'over a range from *A* to *B*'. This usage is pretty common, [as you can see](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=nBRhVqbaJeeK8QeooIPwAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22over%20a%20range%20from%20*%20to%20*%22).

In my sentence I have 3 values, an initial, a peak and a final. How would we describe the range in this case? Here's what I am working with.

> Experiments were carried out over a range from an initial temperature of *A*, peak temperature of *B* and final temperature of *C*.'

Is this usage correct? If not, can anyone suggest a better option? Please note that the '**range**' aspect is relevant because the experiments were also carried out at several temperatures between *A*, *B* and *C*.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested sentence is correct and might be reworded as

> Experiments were carried out over a range of temperature between B and C using an initial temperature of A.

However, strictly speaking eventhough you have three temperatures, the range of those three are still governed by two two end points. If the experiment is exothermic then the range would be your initial temperature and your peak temperature. Also from what you are describing, it sounds like the initial temperature has importance to be mentioned separately.